# Parallelization with procedural functions, e.g. `AddTo`, `PreIncrement`, and so on

Tags: parallelization, procedural-programming

I have a problem that procedural functions don't work with parallelization, e.g. `AddTo` and `PreIncrement`. At first, I thought it is trivial because procedural functions need to read the value that is stored in the variable when the function is called and this process conflicts when multiple cores try to read and update the variable simultaneously.

Here is an example.

The following code works fine, the counter stores 10 after the calculation.

```
counter=0;
Table[PreIncrement[counter],{i,1,10}]
counter
(* 10 *)
```

On the other hand, the following code doesn't work fine, the counter stores 0 after the calculation.

```
counter=0;
ParallelTable[PreIncrement[counter],{i,1,10}]
counter
(* 0 *)
```

However, I thought, if the other cores wait until a core read and updates the value stored in the variable, no conflict occurs and parallelization would still speed up the calculation.

Is there any way to implement my idea in Mathematica? Or any other workaround is also welcome that makes procedural functions work fine under parallelization.

My calculation relates to very large arrays and parallelization is necessary. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: *if the other cores wait until a core read and updates the value stored in the variable* then you would have multiple cores executing a serial computation, and pay a (time) cost in the overhead required for them to politely await on each other finishing.  Or have I missed something in your thought process?

Comment: Please include details about your ACTUAL problem rather than this toy example. It is very possible that an entirely different approach that avoids procedural steps may be available.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark You're right. My idea might end up with the speed that the usual single-core process attains.

Comment: @MarcoB Okay, I posted a detailed version as another question. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/288406/41001